# How to create an Object ID for Parse using swift, only once in the iOS application lifecycle and then use the same ID to update values?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am making an iOS game, and want to implement Parse to keep track of some values like high score and total number of games played. I want the application to generate one Object ID for one user in its entire life, and use the same ID to update the changes in score.

Currently, my approach is to check whether NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults has been set, that is if it is not equal nil. If yes, then is the value is not equal to the String "parseObjectIdNotSaved", then create the Object ID.

However, this throws an error:

```
func parseProfileIdExists() {

    var profileIdDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("playerProfileObjectId") as! String

    if profileIdDefault != (nil) && ("playerProfileObjectId"){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        GameState.sharedInstance.playerProfileObjectId = defaults.stringForKey("playerProfileObjectId")!
    } else {
        println("This worked")
        GameState.sharedInstance.createObjectIdForParse()
    }
}
```

I have a variable var playerProfileObjectId = "parseObjectIdNotSaved" which I use to set some initial value.
The createObjectIdForParse function:

```
func createObjectIdForParse(){
    //For Parsing Data
    playerProfile["highScore"] = GameState.sharedInstance.highScore
    playerProfile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
            GameState.sharedInstance.playerProfileObjectId = self.playerProfile.objectId!
            println(" GameVC - Player profile ID is: (GameState.sharedInstance.playerProfileObjectId)")
        } else {
            println(" Player profile data will be saved eventually")
            self.playerProfile.saveEventually()
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest any better way to do this. This will be my first app and I do not have a strong programming background.

Answer (score 0):

When working with functions which return optionals a best practice is to assign and check as follows:

```
if let profileIdDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("playerProfileObjectId") as? String {
    // object profileIdDefault is the found object with key "playerProfileObjectId"
}
```

The "if let..." basically tries to assign the return value of the called function to a constant "profileIdDefault". This if condition fails if nil (not found) is returned.